# Speeding up a MySQL query / 2.9m rows / multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, query-performance

I have a query that's running quite slow due to a table containing 2.9m rows and the joins to other tables. I've managed to half the execution time but it's still not quick enough.

Does anyone have any ideas on what more I can do? The amount, entityId, merchant.name, channel.uuid, and channel.sender columns are all indexed.

This is the original query which takes 11 seconds...

```html
SELECT 
    SUM(t.amount) AS amount, 
    m.name 
FROM 
    transactionsV2 t
    JOIN channels c ON t.entityId = c.uuid
    JOIN merchants m ON c.sender = m.uuid
WHERE 
    t.paymentType = "DB"
    AND t.status = 1
    AND t.processing_time >= "2019-01-19 00:00:00"
    AND t.processing_time <= "2019-01-20 23:59:59"
GROUP BY m.uuid
ORDER BY m.name
```

This is the reworked query which is taking 4.5 seconds...

```html
SELECT 
    SUM(t1.amount) AS amount, 
    m.name 
FROM
    (
        SELECT t.amount, t.entityId 
        FROM transactionsV2 t
        WHERE 
            t.paymentType = "DB"
            AND t.status = 1
            AND t.processing_time >= "2019-01-19 00:00:00"
            AND t.processing_time <= "2019-01-20 23:59:59"
    ) t1
    JOIN channels c ON t1.entityId = c.uuid
    JOIN merchants m ON c.sender = m.uuid
GROUP BY m.name
```

Below is the table structure for all 3 tables.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: update your question and add  the indexes  you are related  to these tables

Comment: I've added the indexes to the question.

Comment: looks like a **invalid** ANSI SQL GROUP BY query.. `SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS amount, m.name ... GROUP BY m.uuid`.. General rule the used columns in the SELECT clause could also be in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: I don't quite understand @RaymondNijland.

Comment: What query time are you aiming for, and does it need to be up to date or could you cache ?

Comment: At least 2 seconds if possible. Needs to be up to date as transactions are going into the transactions table every second.

Comment: PIeas give the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE transactionsV2` to MySQL and [edit] your question to show us the result. That shows the indexes. And, please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: Including the execution plan for the current query would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your code be sure you have composite index  on

```
transactionsV2 (paymentType, status, processing_time, entityId, amount)

channels (sender, uuid)

merchants ( uuid, name)
```

Comment: All those columns are indexed.

Comment: how are indexes ? .. composite index . or separated  index .?. show the table index

Comment: I've added images of table structure to the original post.

Comment: based on image is impossible check if you are using composite index  or seevral separated  .. index  .. for better performance  (as in my answer ) you must check that you are really using  the composite index  suggested  or equivalent  ..

Comment: I've not created this database nor the tables so I'm unsure whether they're composite or separated indexes. I'll look into this though. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `CREATE INDEX paymentHelper ON transactionsV2 (paymentType, status, processing_time, entityId, amount);` You need a composite index to accelerate this query. Indexes on individual columns aren't the same as a composite index.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by rewriting the query without a derived table:

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS amount, 
       m.name 
FROM transactionsV2 t JOIN
     channels c
     ON t.entityId = c.uuid JOIN
     merchants m
     ON c.sender = m.uuid
WHERE t.paymentType = 'DB' AND
      t.status = 1 AND
      t.processing_time >= '2019-01-19' AND
      t.processing_time < '2019-01-21'
GROUP BY m.name;
```

Then you want indexes that include all the columns for each table.  Assuming that `transactionsV2` is a table, then:

- `transactionsV2(paymentType, status, processing_time, entityId, amount)`
- `channels(uuid, sender)`
- `merchants(uuid, name)`

The idea is to take the columns starting in the `WHERE` with equality conditions first.

If `transactionsV2` is a view, you may be out-of-luck, because MySQL makes it hard (impossible?) to optimize views.